# Specify order to Spring @Autowired

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, autowired, spring-annotations

I am using Spring Framework 4.

I have a class (say ClassA) in which another class (say ClassB) is been used. ClassA's member variables are getting value from ClassB. ClassB has a static method which read data from properties file. In ClassB a static member variable `ApplicationContext` is been injected using `@Autowired` annotation.

What I want is, I want to make sure that when ClassA uses's its member variable it should get all set with values read from properties file. And for that ClassB should get `ApplicationContext` all set to read from `MessageSource`.

As ClassA is marked as `@Component`, Spring loads ClassA, but when it tries to initialize member variables, it is getting `NullPointerException`, as `ApplicationContext` is not yet initialized.

So my question here is, Is there any way available to let Spring tell that some bean should be initialized at some order or something like that. I tried using `@DependsOn` annotation and specified `@Bean` to the getter method of `ApplicationContext`. But it gives below exception:

`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'applicationContext': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?`

Any idea on this issue?

Thanks

Comment: If what you want to do is read properties from the message source, you should check out the @Value annotation and avoid injecting the whole application context. Each class should have the least possible dependencies

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for comments.

I found the solution in one of the annotations supplied by Spring Framework.

Solution of `@DependsOn` annotation worked. Actually when I was using @Bean above getter method of `ApplicationContext` it was firing exception as mentioned in the question. Then I read the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/DependsOn.html) of `@DependsOn` annotation. It states that this annotation is applicable on @Bean and @Component. As the class in which `ApplicationContext` was being injected, I've made ClassA `@DependsOn` the `@Component` class where `ApplicationContext` is being injected and it works.

Thanks again for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

If your purpose is to use a `MessageSource`, use the built-in support, as explained [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#context-functionality-messagesource).

In general, don't `@Autowire` static fields, use `@Value` and `PropertySourcePlaceholderConfigurer` for properties.

Comment: I've tried to inject MessageSource in same manner as mentioned on the link. But it gives same error as the case with ApplicationContext.

Answer (score 1):

Here a good example for the solution given by @Parth Bhagat.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-depends-on